# Trigger click event once Ajax post is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I am trying to trigger a click event once and Ajax post is complete. However, it is not firing because the element is not available in the DOM. I call a jQuery `.load` method in the `success` callback of the Ajax post to load the new DOM element.

**Ajax post:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $formAction,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.constructor === Array) {
            $categoryValidationPanel.html('');
            $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                $categoryValidationPanel.append("<li>" + result[index].ErrorMessage + "</li>")
            });
        } else {
            $dialog.modal('hide');
            refreshComplaintCategoryResults(); //Call to load method below
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("There was a problem processing your request, please try again.");
    }
}).done(function () {
    $("tr[data-action-url='/Admin/ComplaintWorkflow/Edit?categoryId=" + $categoryId + "']").trigger("click");
});
```

**Load method:**

```
function refreshComplaintCategoryResults() {
    $(".complaint-category-results").load('ComplaintWorkflow/GetComplaintCategoryResults');
}
```

I would expect the order of execution to be:

1. Ajax post
2. On success load newly created element into DOM via `refreshComplaintCategoryResults()`
3. do `.done` and trigger click on
   newly created DOM element

However, this is not the case, the `.load` method call is in *pending* state until after the `.done` is executed and hence the DOM is not updated.

**I have also tried this in the .load method (passing the categoryId from the ajax post):**

```
function refreshComplaintCategoryResults(categoryId) {
    $(".complaint-category-results").load('ComplaintWorkflow/GetComplaintCategoryResults', function () {
        $("tr[data-action-url='/Admin/ComplaintWorkflow/Edit?categoryId=" + categoryId + "']").trigger("click");
    });
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here?

**UPDATE:**

I have now got newly created element in the DOM and then the relevant trigger code being executed, however, for some reason it does not execute. I updated the load method to (thanks @TrueBlueAussie for his comments on this):

```
function refreshComplaintCategoryResults(categoryId) {
    $.get("ComplaintWorkflow/GetComplaintCategoryResults", function (result) {
        $(".complaint-category-results").html('');
        $(".complaint-category-results").html(result);
    })
    .done(function () {
        $("tr[data-action-url='/Admin/ComplaintWorkflow/Edit?categoryId=" + categoryId + "']").trigger("click");
    });
}
```

The trigger code is not working. I have debugged in the console and the selector definitely works. If I let the code run through and then execute the same code in the console, the trigger works.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try adding `async: false` in the ajax params?

Comment: Don't add `async: false`. It's bad practice and may block the UI thread while the request executes.

Comment: I didn't think I should add that. I tried anyway and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: you can use it in `complete:function(){ // trigger here... }`.

Comment: I have tried with `complete: function() { // trgger here... }` also and it did not help.

Comment: You are assuming the URL will be an exact match to the absolute URL specified. I am guessing you have no match. Test with `alert($("tr[data-action-url='/Admin/ComplaintWorkflow/Edit?categoryId=" + $categoryId + "']").length);` inside your done function.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Correct, I have no match because the DOM element has not been loaded. However, based on my Ajax call I expect it to be. Please read my question again. After the DOM element is loaded I run that exact bit of code in the console and it works.

Comment: You need to chain Ajax promises and only use `done` (and not `success:`) to do that. You won't be able to use `load` as it does not return a `promise`. You could insert a deferred into your current mix but it will start to get messy.

Comment: Can I use something instead of load? and add it in the done chained to the ajax?

Comment: I guess triggering click in load method (passing the `categoryId` from the ajax post) should work. Is that a typo in there (`$categoryId` instead of `categoryId`)?

Comment: @mg007 yes, thats a typo, sorry. I tried triggering the click in the load method, but that didnt work either.

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery deferred objects is the best solution here. You can chain the callback as required after the completion of ajax request.Here is a link about how to use jquery deferred objects - http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Can you give me an example using the code in my question?

Comment: I've just tried this and it didn't work. The DOM has not refreshed for the `.trigger()` to work on the newly created element as its not there.

Comment: Perhaps, then you have to create another deferred object which checks the status of function refreshComplaintCategoryResults and check for its success and then trigger click only if it successful. I can give you an idea to use deferred objects not the complete code.